# Static String conundrum mystery behaviour

Tags: java, static, behavior

I have two classes. class `Test` and class `Application`. Test class `implements Runnable` and is a thread..of course.

Both classes have public static void main.

> First:

First I launch the `Test` class in which there is a class level variable "a"

```
public static String a = "abc";
```

That points to a string object and Inside the Thread I am just assigning it a new value and printing that value.

> Secondly:

I launch my `Application` class that also have a main method and I just printed the `Static String` in class `Test` and surprisingly it prints "abc". Please note that I launched the second class after starting of my `Test` class. Ideally it should print `NULL` as because of Java Sandbox in which every process runs and one process should not access other process.

Now my question is why ? Why it shouldn't printed the new assigned String. I am giving both classes below

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author AZ
 */
public class Test implements Runnable {

   public static String a = "abc";


    @Override
   public void run(){

        while(true){
           System.out.println(a); 
           a = new Date().toString();
           try {
               Thread.sleep(2000);
           } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
        }      
   }
}
class ThreadRunner {
   static public void main(String args[]){
       new Thread(new Test()).start();
   }
}
```

Second Class

```
import com.springhibernate.beans.MessageBean;
import com.springhibernate.beans.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

/**
 *
 * @author AZ
 */
public class Application {


    public static void main(String args[]){


         System.out.println("Test of printing String " + Test.a);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each process has its own copy of the static field.

However, each process also runs the class intializer, so each copy of the field is intialized to `abc`.

Comment: It means if there is a static class it should also be loaded twice on multiple runs

Comment: Please suggest me any book. I want to know further more about JVM and stuff related to it.